# Python - ensure I'm running the same package versions in both Windows and Linux

Tags: python, algorithm, release-management

I have a Windows 10 machine that I'm using to develop my code (Anaconda 3.5). Now I need to get my code running on a Linux server, so that others can use it as part of an application. What is the best way of setting up and maintaining my Linux environment so that it replicates the Windows one in terms of packages and version numbers?

I'm training and saving DataFrames, SVMs (Sklearn) and ANNs (Keras) in my Windows environment, which is running Anaconda Python 3.5.

On the Linux server I need to be able to load and use these models, which requires having the same packages and package versions.

How do I keep the environments running the same package versions?

The plan is to release newer and better models as I get more data. These might run on newer versions of Keras, Sklearn etc. as versions are released. How can I ensure that in Python I can have the latest package versions but still be able to run older models (possibly trained and saved using older package versions) if required? Backwards compatibility is very important.

Background: 
I'm creating a 'sizing algorithm' that uses a number of ANNs and SVMs. For others to use this algorithm it's going to be running on a Linux server and somehow (the software guy ensures me it can be done) integrated, or linked, into the companies software. The different models will be loaded and saved to memory and used when called to size something. It is important that the older sizing algorithms can still be used even as I release newer, better versions.

Apparently I am the companies Python expert, even though I have only been using it since January and have no experience in releasing algorithms for others to use. I would really appreciate your help in the best way of setting up the system.

Many thanks

Comment: Start by reading about [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) which can be used to install later.

Comment: Have you ever tried exploring Docker ? I think using this would solve your problem. https://www.docker.com/

Answer (score 0):

On a machine with the correct packages:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

On machines that need the correct packages, having copied that file to it:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: aha! That's great. But how do I ensure I can still run older versions? Will this work with Docker?

Comment: The requirements file will grab the specific version number of everything you're using, and pip will then find those online. No reason it wouldn't work in Docker, but I haven't tried.